# RECORDING A FORMULA ON EXCEL MACRO

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make my work easier here and I've run into a problem which not only I don't know how to solve but I also don't know why is it happening in the first place.
So I tried to record a macro and in order to fullfill my need and I need to do some calculations based on two different values. Anyway. Whenever I try to record a macro and I insert this formula everything is ok!

```
=
IF(C1="LPPD";"MIPRU";
IF(C1="LPGR";"DCT";
IF(OR(C1="LPFL";C1="LPCR");"LADOX";
IF(OR(C1="LPPI";C1="LPSJ";C1="LPHR");"NOTMA";
"ERRO"))))
```

For the other two I have I know the formulas work because i get the expected results from them, but Excel's Macro Recorder pops up with a message saying "unable to record".
Here are the other two formulas:

```
=
IF(C1="LPGR";"00:15";
IF(C1="LPPD";"00:30";
IF(AND(E1="DH8D";OR(C1="LPSJ";C1="LPHR"));"00:25";
IF(AND(E1="DH8B";OR(C1="LPFL";C1="LPCR"));"01:00";
IF(AND(E1="DH8B";OR(C1="LPPI";C1="LPSJ";C1="LPHR"));"00:30";
IF(AND(E1="DH8D";C1="LPPI");"00:20";
IF(AND(E1="DH8D";C1="LPFL");"00:40";
"ERRO")))))))
```

And the other one:

```
=
IF(OR(C1="LPPI";C1="LPSJ";C1="LPHR");"FL100";
IF(AND(E1="DH8B";C1="LPPD");"FL120";
IF(AND(E1="DH8D";C1="LPPD");"FL180";
IF(AND(E1="DH8B";C1="LPGR");"FL060";
IF(AND(E1="DH8D";C1="LPGR");"FL080";
IF(AND(E1="DH8B";OR(C1="LPFL";C1="LPCR"));"FL140";
IF(AND(E1="DH8D";C1="LPFL");"FL180";
"ERRO")))))))
```

For some reason Excel doesn't let me record this formulas. Would you geniouses figure out why? I really hope you can help me out here!
Converting this formulas to VBA would be a pain in the **** as with this method I can simply enter the formulas on the first row and then drag to extend them to the following lines...

With my best regards.

Comment: I believe this is VBA limitation to have maximum of 255 characters in one line. Your formulas have more than this, hence can't be strictly translated into VBA.

Comment: I can enter that formula into Excel while recording a macro.  Is `AND` the correct function name in your locale?

Comment: Surprisingly, I was able to record the formula (with the semi-colons replaced with commas of course) ever with the line breaks.  Have you tried rebooting?...lol.

Comment: Why do you need to record the formula?

Comment: i forgot to mention i'm using excel 2003 at work.. -.-' that's why the semi, collons and i tried a variation with less than 255 characters with the same result!

Comment: i need to record the formula because the final worksheet is supposed to work as a data processor.

Comment: (a) What happens if you copy/paste that formula into an Excel cell while the macro recorder is **not** running?  (b) What happens if you type the formula `=AND(1=1;2=2)` into a cell while the recorder **is** running?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the limitations of the "data processor" requirement. If you don't want to convert your entire process into VBA, I understand that, but is there an issue with having a single, small VBA Function in use, if it was to solve this problem?  How about Named Ranges, is that allowed?

Comment: The AND formula is OK! I can paste the formula with no problems and it works as expected. I came up with the conclusion that the macro recorder is the problem, And the limit is not 255 chars, as I've redup on multiple websites, not at least for excel 2003. I've tried to shorten to formulas and even with less than 255 chars it still brakes the recorder.

Comment: Eventually I kinda had 3 possible ways to solve it but I don't think I can do it alone:

Comment: 1st - Shortening as much as possible these formulas, even tough i can't seem to figure out how else i can push it further apart from taking out the error statement and get the last value as the default value if every other condition fails.

Comment: 2nd - Ditch on all these formulas and use a MIXup of VLookup with a concatenated value of my two columns (basicaly a reference table) but either my excel 2003 is a piece of crap or it's not working as it was supposed to).

Comment: 3rd - Convert these formulas to VBA (would make me loose an entire day on it which i would prefer not to, unless no other solution comes available)

Comment: I'm not sure why you were using the macro recorder at all if you aren't wanting to use VBA.  Or do you think that VBA has to use R1C1 notation (it doesn't) and you can't use R1C1 notation when entering a formula yourself (you can, and switching the option would even allow you to see what your A1 notation formulas that you have already entered look like when expressed in R1C1 notation)?

Comment: I used the macro recorder because I'm automating repetitive steps that one has to do with some data we receive! It's not that I don't want to use VBA. I was just trying to avoid it in this case because there seems to be an easier solution. Even if this the case of 2003 version limitations!

Comment: So does that mean I can use A1 a notation in a VBA code? Because I've looked up for the code of the first formula which went fine and VBA presents me with the corresponding R1C1 one... Brrr that thing is daunting!

Comment: I might try to manually insert the formulas inside the code instead of using the recorder and see if that works then....

Comment: If you use the `FormulaR1C1` property, you need to write the formula in R1C1 notation.  If you use the `Formula` property, you need to write the formula in A1 notation.  Also, be aware that (unless you use the `FormulaLocal` property) formulas in VBA have to be written for the US-EN locale, i.e. American function names, and commas instead of semi-colons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace **all** those semicolons with comma's.  Excel is technically able to use semicolons as a list separator now but it may be confusing the macro.

For example, try this for your third formula:

> ```
> =IF(OR(C1="LPPI",C1="LPSJ",C1="LPHR"), "FL100",IF(AND(E1="DH8B",C1="LPPD"),
> "FL120",IF(AND(E1="DH8D",C1="LPPD"),
> "FL180",IF(AND(E1="DH8B",C1="LPGR"),
> "FL060",IF(AND(E1="DH8D",C1="LPGR"),
> "FL080",IF(AND(E1="DH8B",OR(C1="LPFL",C1="LPCR")),
> "FL140",IF(AND(E1="DH8D",C1="LPFL"), "FL180","ERRO")))))))
> ```

Comment: This is regional settings and your formula will not work if you use a wrong separator. OP's first formula was translated to VBA without any problems.

Comment: i forgot to mention i'm using excel 2003 at work.. -.-' that's why the semi, collons.

Comment: Ah yes, the "old version, locked down @ work" scenario...  I don't miss those days!  It sounds like you'd be fine with converting them to VBA if it wasn't a pain in the <sub>@$$</sub>, is that true?  Might be able to get it done easier than you realize.

Comment: Precisly! I've tought about some solutions, and converting this fornmulas to equivalent VBA code will be a daunting and tedious experience!

Comment: This solution in combination with VBA suggestions on the question comments solved my problem, even tough i had to manually insert the formula inside the macro with the VBE.

Comment: I still don't understand exactly _what_ you're doing and why it has to be done in such a _specific_ way (as there are numerous different way to automate production of templates for recurring reports, etc), but I am nonetheless glad that you got it working.  :)